# Sorting array of objects based on date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects similar to...

```
[
  {
    date: "26/11/2016"
    hourlyRate: 50
    hoursWorked: 10
    name: "Mr G"
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "14/10/2016"
    hourlyRate: 50
    hoursWorked: 10
    name: "Mr A"
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "11/09/2016"
    hourlyRate: 50
    hoursWorked: 10
    name: "Mr H"
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "26/10/2016"
    hourlyRate: 50
    hoursWorked: 10
    name: "Mr L"
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  }
]
```

I need to sort this list based on the most recent dates.

Based on similar problems I have seen this is my code for the solution, the array is being passed in as the `records` argument...

```
function sortRecords (records) {

  var sorted = records.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date); 
  });

  return sorted;

}
```

Can anyone advise on why this is not working? I am just getting back the same unsorted array....

Answer (score 3):

That's because your date String can't be parsed as a valid date, you'd need to rearrange the string you are passing to `new Date()`. For example the following would produce a parsable date:

```
function rearrangeDate(dateString) {
    var r = dateString.split('/');
  return r[1] + "/" + r[0] + "/" + r[2];
}
```

which you then can use

```
function sortRecords (records) {

  var sorted = records.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(rearrangeDate(a.date)) - new Date(rearrangeDate(b.date)); 
  });

  return sorted;

}
```

Comment: Just missing a `+` to concat strings in your function

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    let sorted = 
     [{
        date: "26/11/2016",
        hourlyRate: 50,
        hoursWorked: 10,
        name: "Mr G",
        natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
    },
    {
        date: "14/10/2016",
        hourlyRate: 50,
        hoursWorked: 10,
        name: "Mr A",
        natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
    },
    {
        date: "11/09/2016",
        hourlyRate: 50,
        hoursWorked: 10,
        name: "Mr H",
        natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
    },
    {
        date: "26/10/2016",
        hourlyRate: 50,
        hoursWorked: 10,
        name: "Mr L",
        natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
    }
];

function CreateDate(dateString) {
    var arr = dateString.split('/');
    return new Date(arr[2] , arr[1], arr[0]);
}

function sortRecords(records) {    
    var sorted = records.sort(function (a, b) {        
        return CreateDate(a.date) > CreateDate(b.date);
    });
    console.log(sorted);
}
```

`sortRecords(sorted);`

Produces below output:
[image]

Comment: great thanks :) Although I got this working in the console as it wasn't working in my code. I seem to be having a problem with how I am handling the data from the async call to my server, the array of objects is returning without commas between each objects key value pairs. I shall try fix that and then this should solve my sort problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could also sort date on the basis of the **year-month-day** by reversing the current **day-month-year** :

```js
var list = [
  {
    date: "26/11/2016",
    hourlyRate: 50,
    hoursWorked: 10,
    name: "Mr G",
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "30/10/2016",
    hourlyRate: 50,
    hoursWorked: 10,
    name: "Mr A",
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "11/09/2016",
    hourlyRate: 50,
    hoursWorked: 10,
    name: "Mr H",
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  },
  {
    date: "26/10/2016",
    hourlyRate: 50,
    hoursWorked: 10,
    name: "Mr L",
    natInsNumber: "GG845893G"
  }
]
var result = list.sort((a,b) => a.date.split("/").reverse().join("") - b.date.split("/").reverse().join(""));
console.log(result);
```